# Validating Multiselect CakePHP 3 belongsToMany Entites

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm want to ensure that a multi-select field (belongsToMany) has at least one item checked/selected. I have two entities:

Listings and PaymentTypes - belongsToMany.

My field is created with the helper:

```
echo $this->Form->input('payment_types._ids', ['options' => $paymentTypes, 'multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

In my ListingsModel.php file I have my validator setup as follows:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {

        $validator = new Validator();

        $validator->requirePresence('payment_types._ids');

        return $validator;

}
```

This prevent the save from happening but I don't see any validation error message. Why doesn't the HTML5 form validation work as it does on other fields which are of type text?

Comment: Check this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::multiple

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with this custom rule:

```
->add('delivery_types', [
        'multiple'=>[
            'rule'=>['multiple', ['min'=>1]],
            'message'=>'Select at least one method of delivery method'
        ]
])
```

This isn't especially well documented in the book so hopefully it iwll be of some help to others starting with Cake v.3

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with nested validators - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#nesting-validators.

As an example:

```
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
        $paymentTypesValidator = new Validator();
        $paymentTypesValidator->requirePresence('_ids');

        $validator-> addNested('payment_types', $paymentTypesValidator);

        return $validator;
    }
```

You could then decorate the `$paymentTypesValidator` object with any other rules you require.